# (/(%3C*|<)[^*]?script(%3E)[a-zA-Z0-9]*/gi, '') This regex is not working in IE alone for removing script in sting

Tags: javascript, regex

Below regex is not working in IE alone to remove the script tag from url:

Regex Pattern

```
(/(%3C*|<)[^*]?script(%3E)[a-zA-Z0-9]*/gi, '')
```

code:

```
var testEx= http://tv/header:1<script>as</script>;      
testEX = testEx.replace(/(%3C*|<)[^*]?script(%3E)[a-zA-Z0-9]*/gi, '');     
console.log(testEx);
```

Expected Output:

```
tv/header:1
```

Can you suggest the solution for this?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following regex:

```
/(%3C*|<)[/]?script(%3E|>)[a-zA-Z0-9]*/gi
```

**What I have changed:**

It now matches a an optional slash `'/`' before `'script'`, it also matches a literal '`>`' after `'script'`.

If you now replace with an empty string, you get the expected result.